# Are there any test spy libraries available for Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mocking, bdd, ocmock

I want to take a BDD approach to unit testing in an iOS project, and I just realized that there may not be an existing library that provides test doubles of the [test spy](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Spy.html) variety. Ideally, I'm looking for something similar to [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki), or [RR](https://github.com/btakita/rr).

Before I go and spend a week of free time writing a test spy library, I thought I'd pose the question here on SO first.

So far I've looked at [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) and [Kiwi](http://www.kiwi-lib.info/), but they both seem to be of the traditional [high-specification-by-default mocking frameworks](http://vimeo.com/16285089) that require expectation assertions be set in the [arrange phase, prior to the act phase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert). Obviously, this is hampering my vision of beautiful, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), nested specs (which I plan on authoring in either [Kiwi](http://www.kiwi-lib.info/) or [Cedar](https://github.com/pivotal/cedar)).

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this.

Kiwi definitely does not do this now. You are right that the mocks in it are built for a 'standard' arrange prior to act phase.

Moving on, albeit at first glance, it seems that adding the basics for spy functionality would not require too much reengineering. Every message (barring some implementation important, reserved selectors) that gets to a mock goes through `-[KWMock forwardInvocation:]`.

Essentially, the current `-[KWMock forwardInvocation:]` would need be modified to record/copy all invocations that pass through it, instead of what it does now. This would be the primitive functionality that would allow expectations to be verified later by querying the recorded invocations. Of course, coming up with a nice readable form for verification isn't trivial either.

The spy/mock would still need to know what class/protocol it is standing in for upfront. This is so it will be able to generate valid method signatures for selectors of messages sent to it that allows the runtime forwarding machinery to generate the actual NSInvocation that will be forwarded.

I am preoccupied with other things right now to get an implementation in there, but I'll be happy to answer more questions or merge any pull requests. HTH.

Comment: I appreciate the thoughtful response. I'll leave this open a while longer to see if anyone else wants to contribute ideas, particularly with respect to OCMock.